# Force DNS lookups through specific adapter on OS X?

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx

Is there a way to force DNS lookups through a specific adapter's servers on OS X? I have an ethernet connection and a wifi connection, but I'd like all DNS requests to go through the ethernet connection's servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prioritize the Ethernet service over the Wi-Fi service. Open System Preferences -> Network pane -> Action (gear) menu under the service menu on the left -> "Set Service Order" -> In the service order dialog, drag Ethernet above Wi-Fi. Be sure to apply changes t make them take effect.

Note that this only matters if both interfaces are connected; if not, whichever's connected automatically takes priority. Also, the Wi-Fi service will still have DNS servers listed, they just won't be used since it's not the primary interface.

Comment: This will force all network traffic through that interface as well, but I'd prefer to only use the ethernet connection for internal addresses.

Either way, your point is taken that the primary adapter is the one that handles the DNS requests. That may help me get somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the settings for the primary service defines which DNS server(s) will be used, but do not control which interface DNS queries are sent over -- that's handled by OS X's normal routing algorithms. So if the DNS server is on the same subnet as your Mac's ethernet interface, you could put that DNS server in the Wi-Fi service's DNS tab, make the Wi-Fi interface primary (so its router setting will be used for non-local traffic), and the normal routing system will send DNS queries over the ethernet interface.

Comment: If the DNS server you want to use is not on the ethernet interface's subnet, things get more complicated. In that case, the only idea I have is to create a manual routing table entry to sent to the DNS server over ethernet. Unfortunately, OS X does not have a good way to manage static routes...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the DNS entry on the wifi connection.

Comment: This won't work. OS X always uses the DNS servers from its primary network "service" (interface); if there aren't any, it doesn't resolve DNS (even if there are servers defined for other services). (Actually, there's an exception: if it can't ARP the router of the primary service, it sort of fails over and the DNS settings fail over as well...)